# Gstreamer can't capture video from USB-Camera

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson-nano, usb-camera

I have a ***HikVision MV-CA050-20UC*** **USB-Camera**(USB 3.0). I want to capture video from it on **Nvidia Jetson Nano** in **Ubuntu** by using **gstreamer**. After installing the drivers, `/dev/video0`  shows up after connecting the camera (it also vanishes once the camera is disconnected).

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" name=e ! 'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480' ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, format=(string)YUY2' ! xvimagesink`

or using this command

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=1280,height=720 ! xvimagesink`

and it show me this message without any video:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesnt want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Error getting capabilities for device /dev/video0: It isnt a v4l2 driver. Check if it is a v4l1 driver.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(94): gst_v4l2_get_capabilities (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
system error: No such file or directory
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I am sure that **v4l2** is installed correctly. But it could not detect plugged in usb camera.

```
v4l2-ctl --all


VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: failed: No such file or directory
/dev/video0: not a v4l2 node
```

or this result for 1050Ti system(another system):

```
Failed to query video capabilities: No such file or directory
libv4l2: error getting capabilities: No such file or directory
VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: failed: No such file or directory
/dev/video0: not a v4l2 node
```

also by running `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext`
 I got same message.

**Gstreamer version**

```
gst-inspect-1.0 --version

gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.14.2
GStreamer 1.14.2
Unknown package origin
```

How could I resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that GStreamer is a red herring here. It looks more like a device support issue to me.

Comment: what are the drivers? how did you install it?

Comment: @dafnahaktana  It's just a sdk manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **v4l2src** I used **Aravis** [A vision library for genicam based cameras](https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis) and **pylonsrc** [A gstreamer plugin for image capture from Basler's USB3 cameras. Please read the README before using](https://github.com/zingmars/gst-pylonsrc) and the problem was solved(As I used USB3 camera visions).